# Access local object properties from internal function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a Javascript object that is trying to access a local property from inside a setInterval() in a method, but apparently because it is trying to call the local scope of the function in the setInterval, the local property is returning undefined.  Here's the code:

```
function Timer() {
    this.remaining = 15000;
}

Timer.prototype.start = function() {
this.refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    console.log(this.remaining);
},1000);
}
```

How can I access that local 'remaining' variable?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function Timer() {
    this.remaining = 15000;
}

Timer.prototype.start = function() {
var that = this;
this.refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    //this.adjust(-1000);
    that.remaining -= 1000;
    console.log(that.remaining);
    if (that.remaining <= 0) {
        that.remaining = 0;
        that.status = 'paused';
        clearInterval(that.refreshId);
    }
},1000);
}
```

setInterval functions are called in the global scope.  Therefore, you can cache 'this' as a different variable (for instance, as 'that', which is common amongst developers.)

Another option is to come up with a .bind function or method, which you can find out how to do by searching Google.

Read: [Understanding Javascript Closures with Ease](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/)

Comment: Absolutely, no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function Timer() {
    this.remaining = 15000;
}

Timer.prototype.start = function() {
    this.refreshId = setInterval(function(thisR) {
        console.log(thisR);
    },1000, this.remaining);
}
```

You can pass parameters to the setInteval function, otherwise `this` inside [**setInterval()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) is not your Object.

> **Syntax**
>   var intervalID = window.setInterval(func, delay[, param1, param2, ...]);
>   var intervalID = window.setInterval(code, delay);

Source: [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval)

Comment: Your answer works, but to be totally honest this is just a bit cumbersome and it's what I was trying to avoid.  Josh's answer is what I was looking for.

Comment: @JS, what is best for you is best for you :) Cheers